# Why I am getting an error in method getCell() of phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to copy one sheet of an .xlsx using phpspreadsheet with the following code:

```
$spreadsheet1 = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("files/697D.xlsx");
$clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet1->getSheetByName('Sheet');
$clonedWorksheet->setTitle('Test');
$spreadsheet->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);
```

But when I execute the code I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCell() on
>   null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation.php:2785
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell.php(262):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation->calculateCellValue(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell),
>   true) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet.php(1077):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell->getCalculatedValue() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet.php(1027):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet->writeCell(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\XMLWriter),
>   Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet), 'J1', Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\Worksheet.php(76):
>   PhpOffice in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OfferConfigurator\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Calculation.php
>   on line 2785

EDIT: I´m not an expert in phpspreadsheet, but I realized that maybe with clone it isn´t possible to copy formulas. Can that be the problem?

Comment: if you clone in same file, should use `$spreadsheet1` in `$spreadsheet->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);`.

Comment: @Premlatha That´s not the problem, $spreadsheet is defined in the code, but I haven´t written all the code in the question

Comment: Ok,try `$spreadsheet->addExternalSheet($clonedWorksheet);`.

Comment: @Premlatha I get the same error using  $spreadsheet->addExternalSheet($clonedWorksheet);

Comment: @Premlatha Thank you for your help, finally I resolve the error. The problem was on the writer, that when it tried to write and calculate the formulas I get that error. I solve with this instruction: $writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

Comment: Glad that you solve it. By default, this writer pre-calculates all formulas in the spreadsheet. This can be slow on large spreadsheets.So, we can disable formula pre-calculation by `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);`before save it.